# Filter models by a field that content is models.ForeignKey(User)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I have a

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    active = models.NullBooleanField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.post
```

and now i want to filter my `class Posts` by `created_by=testuser`. For that i do

```
p = Posts.objects.filter(created_by=poster, active=True)
```

whereby `var(poster)` comes from the requested `url(r'^(?P<poster>\w+)/$', views.Posts),`

If i execute it by going to my-domain.tld/testuser i get a `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'testuser'`

If i try to filter in `manage.py shell` i get the error `NameError: name 'testuser' is not defined` if i try to filter by the command `p = Posts.objects.filter(created_by=testuser)`.

How is it done right to filter my field `created_by` that content is models.ForeignKey(User). Is there a solution anyway or should i create additional a `CharField` with creator (poster) as content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p = Posts.objects.filter(created_by__username=poster, active=True)`

poster is just an name (str), you can span relationships and query by user.username using `__`

or you could fetch a user object first by poster

```
user = Users.objects.get(username=poster)
p = Posts.objects.filter(created_by=user, active=True)
```

User model documentation can be found on site: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#users

Comment: Thanks! Faster and better isn't possible ;)